# Sphnix index_exact_words not ignoring stopwords

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx

I have set index_exact_words = 1 on the Sphinx index. When I query "The Darkness", it returns results with the term 'Darkness' at the top, but 'The Darkness' is not the first result. That's probably because it's ignoring the word 'The' as it's in stopwords.txt. How do I tell Sphinx not to treat 'The' as a stopword as I want an exact match?

I am querying using this term : '=The =Darkness'

(Sphinx version: Sphinx 2.0.9-id64-release)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stopwords in Sphinx are not indexed, so it doesn't matter whether you use exact match operator or not.

However, stopwords affect keyword positions. 'Darkness' keyword will have `pos==1` in 'The Darkness' and `pos==0` in 'Darkness'. But you can tweak these behavior using `stopword_step` option. If you set it to `0`, stopwords will not affect keyword positions and documents 'The Darkness' and 'Darkness' will be equal in Sphinx.